# Step size in numdifftools jacobian

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, derivative, numerical-analysis

I would like to get the numerical jacobian matrix of a system of nonlinear equations. I use the module numdifftools 0.9.16 on  python 3.4.
I built a function 'fun' that takes an array X and returns an array Y.
I get the jacobian with the command: `jac=nd.Jacobian(fun)(X)` and works fine.

I also controlled the step size using the command : `jac=nd.Jacobian(fun,step=1e-1)(X)` and it is fine too.

Now, I would like the have two different step sizes depending of the equations such as: `jac=nd.Jacobian(fun,step=[1,1,1e-1,1e-1])(X)`, assuming 4 equations. I want to use 1 for the first two equations and 1e-1 for the others.

Unfortunately this command doesn't work. I couldn't find any example that forces different step size but reading the manual this should be feasible. Nobody has experience on it ? Thanks.

Comment: I would apply Gradient method to each component of the function separately (with own size), and then stack the results.